# AAPT2 error: check logs for details and invalid resource type 'attr' for parent of style

Tags: android, android-studio, aapt2

I opened project from github and try to run it but it is giving two errors.first error is "invalid resource type 'attr' for parent of style
"and second is "aapt2 error: check logs for details".
Here is the link of project i was trying to open.
https://github.com/PragatiShrivastava06/EventShare_AndroidApp

Here is the errors image

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is because of your dependency on:

```
compile 'com.klinkerapps:android-chips:1.0.1@aar'
```

In that AAR's resources they define the style resource named *RecipientEditTextView* incorrectly:

```
<style name="RecipientEditTextView" parent="@android:attr/autoCompleteTextViewStyle">
```

As AAPT2 is saying, a style needs a style resource for its parent, you cannot use an attr.

Contact the owner of that AAR or change to a library that doesn't have this mistake in it.

Comment: Note: you can also override the style in your own module.

Answer (score 1):

It tells you exactly what's wrong.

attr is an invalid resource type for style.

Double click the error and it will bring you to the line that is incorrect.